# Flutter- Send param and check if exist

Tags: dart, flutter

I´m trying to send parameters between two pages in flutter. In one of this pages i need to check if param exist, if exist set this value to variable, if doesn't exist set other value.

The code looks similar to

```
final String item;

  TestPage({Key key, this.item}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  TestPageState createState() => newTestPageState();
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
if (this.¿ITEM? { <--- CAN´T DO THIS
}
```

I can´t call *item* variable in class, in documentation only show how can we show in widget. So, any idea how can i call this variable in the class to do if..else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The State class has a member variable `widget` which you can use to access the StatefulWidget. So for instance you will use `widget.item` to access `item`.

Also consider it *may* be more appropriate to pass the variable to the State class and maintain it there as part of the state if you plan on the item changing at all through the lifetime of the widget.